# NavigationBar is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/navigation_bar.dart' and 'package:flutter_onboarding_slider/navigation_bar.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**i am facing error while running error is this because of packges or something else i have remove all the old code and add new still facing following error.

Error: 'NavigationBar' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/navigation_bar.dart' and 'package:flutter_onboarding_slider/navigation_bar.dart'.
appBar: NavigationBar(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'GoogleMapController' which excludes null.
lib/…/map/map.dart:62

- 'GoogleMapController' is from 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' ('/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-2.1.7/lib/google_maps_flutter.dart').
  package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart:1
  _controller?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
  ^

  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_onboarding_slider/flutter_onboarding_slider.dart';
  import 'package:fyppedometer/mainScreens/Navigation/navigationBar.dart';
  import 'package:fyppedometer/widgets/constants.dart';
  import 'package:fyppedometer/widgets/text.dart';

  class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  ```
  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
  ```

  }

  class _MyHomeState extends State {
  final Color kDarkBlueColor = Colors.cyan;

  ```
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names

  List<String> numbers_Height = [
    for (var i = 1.1; i <= 10.0; i = i + 0.1) i.toString()
  ];
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  List<String> numbers_Weight = [for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) i.toString()];

  int _groupValue = -1;
  String _selectedGender = 'male';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      // color: Colors.amber,
      child: OnBoardingSlider(
        buttonText: 'Start',
        onFinish: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Navbar(),
            ),
          );
        },
        buttonTextColor: Colors.cyan,

        // skipTextButton: Text(
        //   'Skip',
        //   style: TextStyle(
        //     fontSize: 16,
        //     color: kDarkBlueColor,
        //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        //   ),
        // ),
        // trailing: Text(
        //   'Login',
        //   style: TextStyle(
        //     fontSize: 16,
        //     color: kDarkBlueColor,
        //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        //   ),
        // ),
        // trailingFunction: () {
        //   // Navigator.push(
        //   //   context,
        //   //   CupertinoPageRoute(
        //   //     builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
        //   //   ),
        //   // );
        // },

        controllerColor: kDarkBlueColor,
        totalPage: 3,
        headerBackgroundColor: liteblue,
        pageBackgroundColor: liteblue,
        background: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 210, left: 80),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/gender.png',
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 160, left: 60),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/walking.png',
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 200, left: 60),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/human.png',
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        speed: 1.8,
        pageBodies: [
          Container(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'What’s Your Gender',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Calories & Stride length calculation need it ',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white60,
                      fontSize: 21.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: size.height * 0.1,
                        width: size.width * 0.5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(25), // radius of 10
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 65, 103),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Radio<String>(
                              activeColor: Colors.white,
                              value: 'male',
                              groupValue: _selectedGender,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedGender = value!;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            title: text(
                                textData: "Male",
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontsize: 20.0,
                                fontweight: FontWeight.bold),

                            //  Text(_selectedGender == 'male' ? 'Hello gentlement!' : 'Hi lady!')
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Container(
                        height: size.height * 0.1,
                        width: size.width * 0.5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(25), // radius of 10
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 65, 103),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Radio<String>(
                              activeColor: Colors.white,
                              value: 'female',
                              groupValue: _selectedGender,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedGender = value!;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            title: text(
                                textData: "Female",
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontsize: 20.0,
                                fontweight: FontWeight.bold),
                            //  Text(_selectedGender == 'male' ? 'Hello gentlement!' : 'Hi lady!')
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ]),
          ),
          Container(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'How Tall are you?',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 28.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'To Personalize Your Fitness Goal ',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white60,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          height: size.height * 0.10,
                          width: size.width * 0.5,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 145, 174, 225))),
                          child: Center(
                            child: text(
                                textData: "Height",
                                fontsize: 30.0,
                                fontweight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 147, 148, 152)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          height: size.height * 0.13,
                          width: size.width * 0.5,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 89, 89)),
                            // color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                            itemExtent: 100,
                            // controller: fixedExtentScrollController,
                            physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                            onSelectedItemChanged: (i) {
                              print(numbers_Height[i]);
                            },

                            childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                              children: <Widget>[

                                ...numbers_Height.map((String number) {


                                  return Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                       number,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 28.0,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                })
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ]),
          ),
          Container(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'How much do you Weight?',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 28.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'To Personalize Your Fitness Goal ',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white60,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          height: size.height * 0.10,
                          width: size.width * 0.5,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 145, 174, 225))),
                          child: Center(
                            child: text(
                                textData: "Weight",
                                fontsize: 30.0,
                                fontweight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 147, 148, 152)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          height: size.height * 0.13,
                          width: size.width * 0.5,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 89, 89)),
                          ),
                          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                            itemExtent: 100,
                            physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                            onSelectedItemChanged: (i) {
                              print(numbers_Weight[i]);
                            },
                            childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ...numbers_Weight.map((String number) {
                                  return Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      number, //Here is the child value I would like to get
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 28.0,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                })
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 6):

Use `show` and `hide` to import part of a library.

```
// Import only foo.
import 'package:lib1/lib1.dart' show foo;

// Import all names EXCEPT foo.
import 'package:lib2/lib2.dart' hide foo;
```

See [Using libraries](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-libraries) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issues , first import your package with a ***variable***  as follows:-

**`import 'package:QualityCheckApp/upgrade/screens/home/navigation_drawer.dart' as nav;`**

Then use your **class/widget** with this variable.

**`drawer: nav.NavigationDrawer(),`**